# Create components with custom html on the fly

Tags: angular

I have an array with components (for example):

```
this.filters = [ colorFilterComponent, mileageFilterComponent ];
```

All filters (aka components) represents their own HTML. 
Whats the best way to create/render these components on the fly? I would like to maintain these components within this array. So that I can loop through all components (filters) and call a function `applyFilters()` for each component. (strategy design pattern) .

I don't think it's a nice solution to specify a directive for each filter. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like, creating them and destroying? You can use *ngIf for that in a template. Basically:

```
<mileage-filter-component *ngIf="condition">...</mileage-filter-component>
```

And taking control of condition state in Component.
Angular2 docs:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html

**** UPDATE (see comments)****

You should take a look on https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChildren-var.html.

The example you are looking for is(quoting from angular.io):

```
@Component({   selector: 'child-cmp',   template: '<p>child</p>' }) class ChildCmp {   doSomething() {} } @Component({   selector: 'some-cmp',   template: `
    <child-cmp #child1></child-cmp>
    <child-cmp #child2></child-cmp>
    <child-cmp #child3></child-cmp>   ` }) class SomeCmp {   @ViewChildren('child1,child2,child3') children:QueryList<ChildCmp>;   ngAfterViewInit() {
    // children are set
    this.children.toArray().forEach((child)=>child.doSomething());   } }
```

Also take a look on QueryList and ViewChild topics on angular docs!

Comment: I would like to create it within the component itself. Within a placeholder for example. So without directives.

Comment: I maybe don't get the big picture of it, but It seems for me that's not the way you should do it in Angular. You want to add a node to DOM and inject the component there?
Where you want to render the component in document?

Comment: The thing is I need to loop through all these components and call a function. So I need all components in an array maintained.

Comment: So you only want to have an object referring to the component inside another component? You can use @ViewChild (and use them in template)
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child

Comment: I think so... I just want to render all components within this array and be able to loop through them and call a certain function

Comment: Ok I'll update my answer. You don't render it within array. You 'render' them (and hide if you need to) within other component's template and refer to them as ViewChild from the parent component. You can then push those ViewChildren into the array if you want and iterate through it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122801/discussion-between-jmachnik-and-depzor).